# Tab autocompletion in bash vi shell mode

Tags: bash, vi, msys

When using MSYS on a windows platform, I "set -o vi" to use the vi shell mode. Tab autocompletion for files and directories stops working. How to I renable this while remaining in vi shell mode?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try:

```
bind -q complete
```

to see if it's set.

To set it at the Bash prompt:

```
bind '"\C-i":complete'
```

It should already be set by default, but it may be overridden in `/etc/inputrc` or `~/.inputrc` possibly inside a `$if mode=vi` / `$endif` block. You can set for subsequent shell starts by adding this line to your `~/.inputrc` file:

```
"\C-i": complete
```

Comment: Excellent advice. emacs mode had settings, but vi mode did not. Easily added.

Answer (score 0):

For dir/file name completion try: ESC-\ or ESC-= or ESC-*

In my case (ubuntu 18.04) it doesn't work for commands.